# How to loop an XML attribute that is repeating in the parent node?

Tags: xml, xslt

This is my XML (stored in a  table column),

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><report rep_name="test" rep_id="1" rep_link="www.report1.com"> </report>
```

My xsl is something like given in the code part

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
 <html>
     <body>
         <xsl:for-each select="/report">
              <table>
                 <tr>
                   <td>Name: </td>
                   <td> <xsl:value-of select='@rep_name"/> </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                   <td>ID: </td>
                   <td> <xsl:value-of select='@rep_id"/> </td>
                 </tr>
                <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="@rep_link!='NA'">
                 <tr>
                   <td>Link: </td>
                   <td> <xsl:value-of select='@rep_link"/> </td>
                 </tr>
               </xsl:when>
              </xsl:choose>
              </table>
       </xsl:for-each>
   </body>
  </html>
</xsl:tempalte>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

that currently parses and displays the values,

> Name: test
>
> ID: 1
>
> Link: www.report1.com

Now the need is there might be more link attributes flowing in and I have to handle it in loop.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><report rep_name="test" rep_id="1" rep_link="www.report1.com" rep_link="www.report2.com" rep_link="www.report3.com"> </report>
```

In the above xsl if i want to loop the "Link" attribute only, i tried to add the for-each loop as below but it is not working,

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="@rep_link!='NA'">
           <xsl:for-each select ="rep_link">
                 <tr>
                     <td>Link: </td>
                     <td> <xsl:value-of select='@rep_link"/> </td>
                 </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:when>
 </xsl:choose>
```

Output should be like this,

> Name: test
>
> ID: 1
>
> Link: www.report1.com
>
> Link: www.report2.com
>
> Link: www.report3.com

My current XSL version is working fine with current XML values. When i make the changes for loop since something is wrong the whole display is just empty page.

Please help!

I tried introducing the for-each loop but it is not working.

Comment: Derek, thanks for formatting!

Comment: Per [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags): _An attribute name **must not** appear more than once in the same start-tag or empty-element tag._ So you shouldn't have more than one `rep_link` element. If you do, you don't have well-formed XML.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I will get that cleared first!

Comment: Thanks @DanielHaley! Once the XML was correctly formed(added new child tag instead of same attribute) I was able to easily apply the for loop. Many thanks!